# Can I use the CoxPH model for 'count' variable instead of time variable?

Tags: survival, cox-model

I'm working on the survival rate with transaction data.
I can use the transaction date for CoxPH, but I wanna know whether I can try to use the number of transactions instead of the transaction date.

[Edit]

To be specific, I wanna use the number of transactions as a type of time scale. So, the result would be "survival rate is 70% at the 5th transaction".

I actually already tried it, but when I do it with the number of transactions, CLV(the customer lifetime value) is quite different from the CLV with the time variable.

-- I calculate CLV like this (with 5 years of data)
When "with # transaction as time scale" :  Sum of survival rate (meaning that the average number of total transactions)

When "time variable": each survival rate multiplied by the average number of transactions each month, and the sum of them.

I know this is complicated, but my point is that I wanna know if I can use the number of transactions as a time scale instead of a "time variable".

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit the question to say more about how you want “to use the number of transactions instead of the transaction date.“ Do you want to use the total number of transactions to date as a type of time scale, or do you want to model the number of transactions (perhaps individual by individual) as a function of time? Either might be possible, but we’d need more details about your data and what you’d like to accomplish. Please provide that extra information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: I started an answer, but I need some more details about your data. When you say you have "5 years of data," is that 5 years for each customer or a set of data spanning 5 years, with new customers signing up and old customers leaving throughout? For your Cox model, is `time=0` the same calendar date for all, or is that date specific to each customer, like the date of signing up? Are there covariates in the models? Is there a specific event that defines losing a customer, or is that just taken to be absence for some period of time? Again, please provide that information by editing the question.